# Inserting estimates from R to jags

Tags: r, jags

For my research I need to estimate variance, and insert these estimates into the scale matrix (called R in my JAGS-code) of my wishart distribution in JAGS. I use R2JAGS (on a mac) and I would like to know how I could do this with R/JAGS code? I want to do this automatically because I need to run a simulation study.

So I got the following R-code for running my model:

```
Res.NoCorr <- jags(data, model.file = "LVL_3_MODEL_SD_NoRanEff.bug", parameters = 
c("sigma.mean.mu", "sigma.mean.beta", "sigma.mean.phi"), n.chains = 1, n.iter = itt, 
n.burnin = bi, DIC = FALSE)

Res.NoCorr

Inference for Bugs model at "LVL_3_MODEL_SD_NoRanEff.bug", fit using jags,
 1 chains, each with 1e+05 iterations (first 10000 discarded), n.thin = 90
 n.sims = 1000 iterations saved
                mu.vect sd.vect  2.5%   25%   50%   75% 97.5%
sigma.mean.beta   0.121   0.054 0.021 0.082 0.123 0.160 0.222
sigma.mean.mu     1.345   0.608 0.070 0.955 1.398 1.800 2.386
sigma.mean.phi    0.096   0.014 0.069 0.087 0.095 0.106 0.126
```

This is my JAGS code for inserting the estimates manually:

```
Prec.Mat[1:3, 1:3] ~ dwish(R[,], 3) # prior for precision matrix random effects

est.sd.mu <- 1.345
est.sd.beta <- 0.121
est.sd.phi <- 0.096

est.var.mu <- est.sd.mu * est.sd.mu
est.var.beta <- est.sd.beta * est.sd.beta
est.var.phi <- est.sd.phi * est.sd.phi

variance.estimation.mu <- est.var.mu * 3
variance.estimation.beta <- est.var.beta * 3
variance.estimation.phi <- est.var.phi * 3

R[1,1] <- variance.estimation.mu
R[2,2] <- variance.estimation.beta
R[3,3] <- variance.estimation.phi
R[1,2] <- 0
R[1,3] <- 0
R[2,3] <- 0
R[2,1] <- 0
R[3,1] <- 0
R[3,2] <- 0
```

So in this case, I need to program the insertion of the numbers of est.sd.mu, est.sd.beta and est.sd.phi.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you write your JAGS file as a [brew](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/brew/index.html) package template you can do something like this:

```
est.sd.mu <- <%= Xmu %>
est.sd.beta <- <%= Xbeta %>
est.sd.phi <- <%= Xphi %>
[etc]
```

Then then you process this with the `brew` function to generate the JAGS file, with the R variables `Xmu`, `Xbeta`, and `Xphi` set to the values you want to replace.

As an illustration using text for the template:

```
> Xmu=-1.23
> brew(text="est.sd.mu <- <%= Xmu %>")
est.sd.mu <- -1.23
>
```

But you should use a file for the template using the `file=` and `output=` args to specify input template and output JAGS files.

You could do it by using `paste` to assemble a character version of the file in R which you then save as a JAGS file, but that's just duplicating what `brew` is designed for.

Comment: I tried using your suggestion with the brew package, but it does not seem to work. I think it has to do with the `file=` and the `output=` arguments.

This is my R-code for one of the parameters:

`brew(text="est.sd.mu <- <%= Xmu %>", file = "LVL_3_Model_SD.bug", output = "res.Corr")`

Where LVL_3_MODEL_SD.bug is the file with my entire model, and res.Corr is my R object where I want my jags output to be in.

Comment: No, you put the <%= variable name %> tags in LVL_3_Model_SD.bug file, and do `brew("LVL_3_Model_SD.bug", output="LVL_3_Model_SD-out.bug")` and the replacements will appear in the `-out.bug` file. You then feed that to JAGS. Don't use `text=`, that was just me creating a simple example of template replacement.

Comment: thank you for your quick response, it works now!. One final question: I got the following warning, and my question is whether I can ignore it (since it produces the right JAGS file) or not:

Warning message:
In readLines(icon, 1) : incomplete final line found on 'LVL_3_Model_SD.bug'

Comment: Sounds like the last line of your file doesn't have a 'return' on it. Go to the end of the line and hit return, save, try again.